# Generic way to get modified (add, delete, modify) entries in LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, ldap-query, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I need Generic way to get all modified (add, delete, modify) entries in any LDAP servers 
i.e.

- Active Directory
- OpenLdap
- Apache Directory
- and many others

as given in this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114167/view-modified-entries-in-ldapusing-unboundid-api)** There are a number of ways to accomplish this.
we can using one of following control

```
1. com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.controls.ContentSyncRequestControl
2. com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.controls.PersistentSearchRequestControl
3. com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.experimental.ActiveDirectoryDirSyncControl
4. com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.ChangeLogEntry
```

but problem is that some LDAP server support `ContentSyncRequestControl` control
some support `ActiveDirectoryDirSyncControl` and some server does not support any control.
now I have to find a generalized way to find the modified entries in any LDAP.

According to last point in question

> If all else fails, you may be able to use range searches targeting the createTimestamp and/or modifyTimestamp attributes to identify entries created and/or updated after a specified time.

I can get get added and modified entries by there `createTimestamp` and `modifyTimestamp` attributes but I can not able to get deleted users using this approach.

Also I have not get way to search entries using `com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.ChangeLogEntry` class

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: I do hope that someone can answer this, but I really do not think there is a "generic" method that will work across all LDAP implementations.

Comment: @jeemster thanks for reply can you tell how can I search modified entries through com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.controls.ContentSyncRequestControl or 
com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.controls.PersistentSearchRequestControl